# How to set our own colors for curves with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am looking for setting my own colors for on the below plot :

[image: ggplot]

with the following part of code :

```
# Save PDF - Chisquare
pdf(file="Moschopoulos_Distribution.pdf")
color_curve <- c("red", "blue", "green", "grey", "black")
as.data.frame(y3) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%     # add row to simplify next step
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%             # reshape long
  mutate(name = recode(name, V1="z = 0.9595", V2="z = 1.087", V3="z = 1.2395", V4="z = 1.45", V5="z = 1.688")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, color = name)) + # map x to value, color to name
  geom_density() +
  xlab(TeX("Distribution")) +
  ylab("Number of occurences") +
  ggtitle(TeX("Distribution of Ratio $(b_{sp}/b_{ph})^2$ for each redshift")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
dev.off()
```

How could I set my own colors for each curve ?

I tried to do into code snippet above :

```
color_curve <- c("red", "blue", "green", "grey", "black")
ggplot(aes(value, color = color_curve)) +
```

but I get an error.

Comment: You could set your colors via `+ scale_color_manual(values = color_curve)`.

Comment: @stefan . Great, it works  ! thanks

Comment: @stefan, please post as answer ...

Comment: @stefan . By the way, if I don't set my own colors, what are the names or hexacodes of the color of the curves in the plot of my post above ?

Comment: You could get the hex codes of e.g. the first 5 default colors via `scales::hue_pal()(5)`

Comment: @youpilat13: I have removed the answer that was merged into the question. By all means, do post an answer. Click on the blue "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom of the page.